# Reduce Image height on ScrollView scroll

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, imageview, android-scrollview

I'm developing an android app, I have an activity where I show the content of a blog.

In the layout I have this content

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:id="@+id/noteImage" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/content"
                android:layout_weight="1.56" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The last TextView contains a lots of text, so when I scroll down, the image and title are gone, and it will only displays text.

Is there a way when I scroll, to reduce height of the ImageView, using full width, and center vertically to some point, and the force it on top always until I scroll back to top?